# MySQL get n percent of rows matching each unique column value

Tags: mysql, mariadb

With `10.3.17-MariaDB` I'm trying to get 50% of the rows matching each unique value in a specific column. Using the example below, for each unique Code, I'd like to get 50% of all the rows with that code.

Suppose my table is as such:

```
Name  Code
A     200
B     300
C     300
D     400
E     400
F     400
G     400
```

Notice for example that B & C have code 300, and D, E, F, G all have code 400.

Desired output from query:

```
Name  Code
A     200    < 1 of 1
B     300    < 1 of 2
D     400    < 1 of 4
E     400    < 2 of 4
```

Update: The selected answer provides the correct results. The question was lightly edited to provide more clarity.

Comment: What happens if you have an odd number of rows (>1) , 3 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COUNT()` window functions:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by code order by name) rn,
    count(*) over (partition by code) counter
  from tablename  
)
select Name, Code
from cte
where rn <= ceiling(counter * 0.50)
```

With `ceiling()` when the number of rows for a `code` is odd you will get 1 more row (for example if there are 5 rows you will get 3 in the results).
If you don't want this change to:

```
where rn <= counter * 0.50 or rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=7c95e76a0283cc4ca317857853aefa20).
Results:

```
> Name | Code
> :--- | ---:
> A    |  200
> B    |  300
> D    |  400
> E    |  400
```

Answer (score 0):

You could allocate a row number to each group of codes and compare against a count

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT NAME,CODE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY NAME) rN FROM T
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE CTE.RN <= (select count(*) / 2 from t where t.code = cte.code group by code) or
cte.rn = (select count(*) from t where t.code = cte.code group by code having count(*) = 1);
```